# Merge two SQL data tables in asp.net website using vb.net in code behind

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to find a solution that fits.

Here is the situation. I have a two SQL queries from the same table each with a different where clause.

Table A uses this SQL statement:

```
Select   jo.AssemblySeq As Assm,
         jo.OprSeq As [OP Center #],
         jo.WCCode As WC,
         Convert(Varchar, jo.DueDate, 101) As [Due Date],
         ja.RequiredQty As Qty,
         jo.QtyCompleted As [Qty Comp],
         jo.OpComplete As OpComplete
From     JobOper jo
Join     JobAsmbl ja
    On jo.JobNum = ja.JobNum
       And jo.AssemblySeq = ja.AssemblySeq
Where    jo.JobNum Like '236087.%'
         And ja.AssemblySeq <> 0
Order By jo.AssemblySeq;
```

And returns this data:

[image]

Table B uses this SQL query:

```
Select   jo.AssemblySeq As Assm,
         jo.OprSeq As [OP Center #],
         jo.WCCode As WC,
         Convert(Varchar, jo.DueDate, 101) As [Due Date],
         jo.QtyPer As QTY,
         jo.QtyCompleted As [Qty Comp],
         jo.OpComplete As OpComplete
From     JobOper jo
Join     JobAsmbl ja
    On jo.JobNum = ja.JobNum
       And jo.AssemblySeq = ja.AssemblySeq
Where    jo.JobNum Like '236087.%'
         And ja.AssemblySeq = 0
Order By jo.AssemblySeq;
```

And returns this data:

[image]

What I need to do is merge these two tables so that I have columns called Assm, OP Center #, WC, Due Date, Qty, Qty Completed, OpComplete. My problem is that the where clause for the query for table A has ja.AssemblySeq <> 0 and the where clause for the query for table B has ja.AssemblySeq = 0.

I need all the lines from both queries. I am not sure if I need some type of Join or if it would involve sub queries?

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET and VB.NET?

Comment: I am using VB.Net in the ASP.NET web site that connects to the SQL database

Comment: How is that relevant though? If you simply want to combine two queries together in SQL, then that's not relevant at all.

Comment: Please explain. Do you need to extract the two distinct datatables for other purposes or you just want to retrieve a single DataTable making a single query?

Comment: I added the VB.Net and ASP.Net to complete. I have seen question on here that are like this and get down voted because they didn't mention that it was going into VB and/or ASP. Just wanted to make sure I had everything covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple UNION ALL will help as below:

```
Select * from Query1
  Union All
Select * from Query2
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do a `UNION ALL` at all.  You can do this with one single query, without the need to hit the table twice.

Your queries are identical with the exception of the column selected based on the value of `ja.AssemblySeq`.  You can just remove the `WHERE` clause altogether and make the `Qty` column a `CASE` expression.

```
Select   jo.AssemblySeq As Assm,
         jo.OprSeq As [OP Center #],
         jo.WCCode As WC,
         Convert(Varchar, jo.DueDate, 101) As [Due Date],
         Case When ja.AssemblySeq = 0 
             Then jo.QtyPer 
             Else ja.RequiredQty 
         End As Qty,
         jo.QtyCompleted As [Qty Comp],
         jo.OpComplete As OpComplete
From     JobOper jo
Join     JobAsmbl ja
    On jo.JobNum = ja.JobNum
       And jo.AssemblySeq = ja.AssemblySeq
Where    jo.JobNum Like '236087.%'
Order By jo.AssemblySeq;
```